# Read a File and store into a string

Tags: c

Hello im trying to do a simple program that will read a text and store into a string and in the end return it to where i called my function. What i have until now is this:

```
void crawler() {


FILE *file;
char line[256], letra[256];
int j = 0;
file = fopen("teste.txt", "r");

letra[j] = fgetc(file);
j++;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {

    for(int i = 0; line[i] != 00; i++)
    {
        if(line[i] == 46)
        {
            if(line[i+1] == 46)
            {
                letra[j] = " ";
                j++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            letra[i] = line[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

But i don't know if this is the correct way. Should i do a dynamic Char instead using malloc? What is the best approach to what im trying to do?

[Edit]

Im getting an error in this line: `letra[j] = " ";`

> incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Comment: You're not returning anything, and don't be tempted to return the address of your buffer, because it's on the stack, and will become invalid as soon as you return.  So yes, I would `malloc` a buffer.

Comment: Why are you moving the read data around? First you read it into `line` and them you copy it to `letra`. Why and what for?

Comment: What is so special about 46?

Comment: ForceBru - Because i need to do some treatment do the text. 46 is the Decimal for "." and some parts of the texts are like "hello..,who are you doing?" So there is two dots instead of a space thats why i copy into another array, but i could use the same array anyway. And yes i still didnt put any return but i didnt reach the return part yet.

Comment: Change `letra[j] = " "` to `letra[j] = ' '`. And did you mean (6 lines below) `letra[i] = line[i]` should be `letra[j] = line[i]`?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but would using malloc() cause a problem in freeing the buffer? How about having the calling program provide a pointer to a buffer instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `" "` is a string and you're attempting to assign it to a `char` data type. In C, strings are handled by the `char *` data type which is a pointer. You cannot convert a pointer to a different data type, thus the error.

You should do this instead:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {

    for(int i = 0; line[i] != 00; i++)
    {
        if(line[i] == 46)
        {
            if(line[i+1] == 46)
            {
                letra[j] = ' ';
                j++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            letra[i] = line[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

I also see a potential hazard in `letra[i] = line[i];` but that is not what your question is about.

Personal note: You can easily type-cast between `char` and `int` datatypes equally because they are both a byte of storage. This makes it easy to do some math with letters by casting them as `int` before calculating.

Comment: Re your last paragraph: `char` and `short` are promoted to `int` before arithmetic operations. And the literal value `'a'` is of type `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought that the `int` data type was 8 bits, but you're suggesting that `short` is 8 and `int` is 16? It's been a while since I did any C programming that dealt with numbers. Most of my stuff is string parsing and command processing.

Comment: `int` is not less than 16 bits, but more usually 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: So are all `int` of the type `long int` then? I thought the `long int` was the 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves yours question,

```
#include<stdio.h>

FILE *pfile;
char fileData[200],letter;
int ind;

void storeData();

int main()
{ 
 storeData();
 printf("Data From File:\n");
 printf("%s",fileData);
 return 0;
}

void storeData()
{

  ind=0;
  pfile=fopen("textf.txt","r");
  while((letter=fgetc(pfile))!=EOF)
  {
   fileData[ind]=letter;
   ind++;
  }
  fileData[ind]='\0';

}
```